# Tests started to fail moving a class into its own file

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, karma-jasmine

I had two classes that were on the same file and implemented same methods so I decided to split them in two files and have the base class implement an interface

The base class looks like this

```js
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class PlatformItemHandler implements ItemHandler<PlatformSwimlaneItem> {
```

The class that inherists from that class looks like this

```js
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class PlatformTemplateItemHandler extends PlatformItemHandler {
```

When the tests run and fail, the error is

> Error: This constructor is not compatible with Angular Dependency
> Injection because its dependency at index 16 of the parameter list is
> invalid.

```
22:22:54    Error: This constructor is not compatible with Angular Dependency Injection because its dependency at index 16 of the parameter list is invalid.
22:22:54    This can happen if the dependency type is a primitive like a string or if an ancestor of this class is missing an Angular decorator.
22:22:54    
22:22:54    Please check that 1) the type for the parameter at index 16 is correct and 2) the correct Angular decorators are defined for this class and its ancestors.
22:22:54        at <Jasmine>
22:22:54        at ɵɵinvalidFactoryDep (/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/cake/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.goog.js:861:11)
22:22:54        at NodeInjectorFactory.TemplateListComponent_Factory [as factory] (ng:///TemplateListComponent/ɵfac.js:13:66)
22:22:54        at getNodeInjectable (/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/cake/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.goog.js:3944:44)
22:22:54        at instantiateAllDirectives (/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/cake/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.goog.js:8333:25)
22:22:54        at createDirectivesInstances (/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/cake/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.goog.js:7723:5)
22:22:54        at ɵɵelementStart (/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/cake/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.goog.js:14479:9)
22:22:54        at BrandTemplateComponent_ng_container_7_ng_template_12_lucid_template_list_3_Template (ng:///BrandTemplateComponent.js:214:5)
22:22:54        at executeTemplate (/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/cake/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.goog.js:7696:9)
22:22:54        at renderView (/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/cake/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.goog.js:7521:13)
22:22:54        at TemplateRef.createEmbeddedView (/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/cake/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.goog.js:10364:17)
22:22:54 HeadlessChrome 86.0.4240 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 24 of 28 (4 FAILED) (skipped 3) (0 secs / 18.19 secs)
```

Taking at look at the the *.spec.ts" file the constructor has this parameters, the parameter at index 16, starting from 0, is

```js
    constructor(
        zone: NgZone,
        changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
        private user: User,
        private templateCategoryList: TemplateCategoryList,
        private sectionSelection: TemplateSectionSelection,
        private sectionTemplateList: SectionTemplateList,
        private valueSelection: TemplateCategoryValueSelection,
        private _lastSelectedDocument: LastSelectedDocument,
        private _infoPanelVisible: InfoPanelVisible,
        public starredTemplates: StarredTemplates,
        public unsharedTemplates: UnsharedTemplates,
        public brokenTemplates: BrokenTemplates,
        public smartTemplates: SmartTemplates,
        public popularTemplates: PopularTemplates,
        private managingCategories: ManagingCategories,
        public templatePreview: TemplatePreview,
        private visibleTemplateList: VisibleTemplateList,
        @Inject(Router) router: Router,
        @Inject(ActivatedRoute) route: ActivatedRoute,
        public documentListLoadStatus: DocumentListLoadStatus,
        private paywallManager: PaywallManager,
        private analytics: Analytics,
        private selectedCategoryValue: SelectedCategoryValue,
        public testManager: TestManager,
        private readonly amplitudeClient: AmplitudeClient,
        private readonly templateSectionLabels: TemplateSectionLabels,
```

That parameter is also injectable.

```js
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class VisibleTemplateList extends Pipe<TemplateWithValues[]> {
```

I have tried

- using `abstract class` instead `of interface`
- removing `@Inject()` to the base class
- Also have tried all the [answers mention here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60149052/this-constructor-is-not-compatible-with-angular-dependency-injection-because-its)

But the problem continues, what can be causing this error, especially since the error being reported does not seem related to my change in code.

Comment: Why is the base class marked as `@Injectable`? That is not required if the class is only used as a base class.

Comment: I have tried without the `injectable` and it also fails, in some discussions people menition that it worked setting injectable on both classes

Comment: For the person that choose to "Close question because it does not follow the SO guidelines" ? what is missing from my question ? it has:  What is the problem, what have I tried, detailed errors, correct tags...

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that a class was importing the previous file

Before

```js
import {PlatformTemplateItemHandler} from '../../platformitemhandler';
```

After

```js
import {PlatformTemplateItemHandler} from '../../platformtemplateitemhandler';
```

And yes the `Injectable` is needed in the base class